# Moment.js display weekend DOY

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Moment.js is awesome, it lets you format dates to whatever format you need. But is there any function that allows you to list all the weekend dates (in DOY format) for the particular year?

Answer (score 0):

it can be done easily using a JS loop and adding dates functionality of moment.js. Take an year set date to 1th of Jan., check the weekday and then go to next date by momentjs function `add(1, 'days')`

hope it helps

Comment: but if I add then I can't add +6 days, as  sometimes ther eis Feb with 28 days. I am trying to find a function like (is_weekend)

Comment: @meso_2600 that's easy add this function to std. Date object Date.prototype.isWeekEnd = function() {
    return this.getDay()==0 || this.getDay()==6;
} and then you can check it on every date.